# Listen the show / hide events for soft keyboard (Windows 8.1 RT, XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How can I know when the soft keyboard is shown/dismissed in my app or within a page?

Found this snipplet in [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972345.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) article. But is not valid for WP 8.1 RT. How can I translate it or get a similar behavior?

```
public class MyApplication
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        // Grab the input pane for the main application window and attach
        // touch keyboard event handlers.
        Windows.Foundation.Application.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing
            += new EventHandler(_OnInputPaneShowing);
        Windows.Foundation.Application.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding
            += new EventHandler(_OnInputPaneHiding);
    }

    private void _OnInputPaneShowing(object sender, IInputPaneVisibilityEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // If the size of this window is going to be too small, the app uses 
        // the Showing event to begin some element removal animations.
        if (eventArgs.OccludedRect.Top < 400)
        {
            _StartElementRemovalAnimations();

            // Don't use framework scroll- or visibility-related 
            // animations that might conflict with the app's logic.
            eventArgs.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
        }
    }

    private void _OnInputPaneHiding(object sender, IInputPaneVisibilityEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_ResetToDefaultElements())
        {
            eventArgs.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
        }
    }

    private void _StartElementRemovalAnimations()
    {
        // This function starts the process of removing elements 
        // and starting the animation.
    }

    private void _ResetToDefaultElements()
    {
        // This function resets the window's elements to their default state.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, registering for those events is enough:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += onKeyboardShowing;
        InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += onKeyboardHidding;
}

private void onKeyboardShowing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    KeyboardVisible = true;
}

private void onKeyboardHidding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{

    KeyboardVisible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The article you quote is intended for Windows Runtime apps, but it has a minor bug. The [InputPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx) is in [Windows.UI.ViewManagement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.aspx) not in Windows.Foundation.Application. Change that and the rest should work fine.

I've reported the doc bug so it can be fixed.